# DropDownList value="" no being retrieved from Database

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a dropdownlist with following options:

```
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTaxStatus" runat="server" OnPreRender="ddlContainerStatus_PreRender">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="'' - Not closed"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="R" Text="R - Ready to pay"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="X" Text="X - Paid"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="C" Text="C - Cancel"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="O" Text="O - Original"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="D" Text="D - Delete"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Based on option selected by user, I send the selected option for search in my database and retrieve records which has the selected value in the related field. My Sql usp looks like this:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetContainerSummaryRecordsForSearch] (
      @fkJobID varchar(8),
      @csmTaxStatus varchar(3)
 )
AS
  BEGIN
      SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

            SELECT fkJobID,
                      csmContainerID,
                      csmDisplayContainerID,
                      csmTaxStatus

               FROM   ContainerSummaryRecord
               where  fkJobID = @fkJobID
                      AND ( @csmTaxStatus IS NULL
                             OR csmTaxStatus = @csmTaxStatus )

  END
```

Now my question, When user selects option with Value="" and  Text="'' - Not closed", I do not get the desired result. This is because value= "" is actually stored as null in DB. 
In query i am comparing input parameter in where clause like this @csmTaxStatus IS NULL
because if user has not selected any option meaning  Text="--Select--" Value="-1", then the filter is not applied and all the results get returned (and this is the desired behavior for this option). But this is clashing with the Value="" which is stored as null in DB. Kindly help.

Comment: Why not select a code for the not closed? call it Z.. & it wont store as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change where condition as

just make use of `isnull()` to resolve issue easily which replace null with blank as below

```
where  fkJobID = @fkJobID                       
AND ( @csmTaxStatus IS NULL                              
     OR isnull(csmTaxStatus,'') = @csmTaxStatus )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could fix this, but you could change your SQL Statement to handle a NULL in csmTaxStatus and convert it to an empty string. If you are passing in @csmTaxStatus as an empty string then you can make use of ISNULL.

```
ISNULL( csmTaxStatus, '' ) = @csmTaxStatus
```

Full SQL statement

```
SELECT fkJobID,
    csmContainerID,
    csmDisplayContainerID,
    csmTaxStatus
FROM   
    ContainerSummaryRecord
WHERE
    fkJobID = @fkJobID
    AND ISNULL( csmTaxStatus, '' ) = @csmTaxStatus
```